# Choosing Netbeans project template or maven's project template

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

I'm little confused because of too many options when we take anything in java. I want to create a web application in java. whether i have create web application from 'java web' or 'maven' by creating new project in netbeans. I may use some archetypes in my future, but whether maven project has full IDE support from netbeans

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Maven projects in NB 7 without a problem.